# How to setup wifi on raspberry pi with username and password on Android Things using adb shell

Tags: wifi, android-things

I have a raspberry pi running an older version of Android things that is capable of connecting to my wifi. I copied and inserted the wpa_supplicant file from that pi to another pi with an updated version of android things but the new pi is unable to connect to the wifi. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

There is [a guide](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/wifi-adb.html) on how to do this.

In the adb shell you can execute this command:

```
am startservice \
-n com.google.wifisetup/.WifiSetupService \
-a WifiSetupService.Connect \
-e ssid my-ssid \
-e passphrase my-passphrase
```